# Should you mention all travellers in Schengen visa cover letter?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, iceland

3 of us are planning to apply for an Icelandic visa from India. Just to be clear and transparent, in the cover letter, we want to mention the details of the other 2 along with the passport numbers that we are flying together.

**The problem:**

No appointments are available for the same date.

**Question:**

Should we still mention the details of the other 2 travellers in our cover letters?

Comment: Will you only travel if all three of you can go or will one or two of you still go if not?

Comment: This must be a common problem for families too, who need individual visas. Could you write a joint letter requesting an interview together?

Comment: @Willeke yes, the trip can only happen if all 3 are going.

Comment: @WeatherVane VFS Global handles Visa appointments here. Are you suggesting we should write a joint letter to VFS?